# Ninject bindings order of execution

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

For a set of bindings like the ones below

```
Bind<ITestInterface>().To<WHenBarHappensTriggerTarr1>()
Bind<ITestInterface>().To<WHenBarHappensTriggerTarr2>()
Bind<ITestInterface>().To<WHenBarHappensTriggerTarr3>()
```

What determines the order of execution if I try getting all instances of IHandle from my IoC container?

Answer (score 3):

The order of the objects when using `GetAll` or injecting an `IEnumerable` is unspecified.

Comment: And how can we make sure the order gets deterministic?

Comment: IMO it is not the job of the IoC container to give the dependencies in some order. E.g. what if different objects need different orders? If the order is relevant then this is a business funtionallity. In that case the code using the dependencies has to order them to its needs. E.g. using OrderBy.